# Error when using mySerialPort.PortName ()

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a software in C #, and I need to list the names of the available serial ports, but when using (PortName ()) the Visual Studio does not recognize the (PortName ()) and the error. What could be wrong? I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and C #.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Control
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ListCOMs()
    {
        int i;
        bool qtde;

        i = 0;
        qtde = false;

        if (cbPorts.Items.Count == mySerialPort.PortName().Length)
        {
            foreach (string s in mySerialPort.PortName())
            {
                if (cbPorts.Items[i++].Equals(s) == false)
                {
                    qtde = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void timerCOM_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListCOMss();
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: All your ports are null.  The serial port object will not have a value until you call the serial port constructor.

Comment: Cool, which constructor should I call? Do you have a tutorial for me to see? Thank you

Comment: new SerialPort.